# Getting an agency to release a client's domain

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registrar, domains

A friend of mine has a website with Therapysites.com (they create therapy sites for alternative therapy providers). She wants to move to a different hosting, but the service provider is charging 15 USD for releasing the domain.

It's a nominal amount, but principally I think its unfair. Is this keeping the domain hostage thing legal?

Comment: There is admin involved with moving hosting / transferring domains and not uncommon to have to pay a small fee for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some registrars charge an administration fee for transferring the domain away, they are likely forwarding this cost to your friend. There is no legal obligation that companies not to charge any fees for the transferring of the domain... It's like switching from one telecom provider to another, some charge, some don't....

While you may consider the charges unfair most companies will include these terms within their terms and conditions which your friend would of agreed to before taking out the services, even though they are not legally required to provide this information if the charge is not excessive and justified. I don't consider £15.00 excessive in this case.

While I don't believe $15.00 is a huge amount it is average, normally they charge between $10-15.00 if a fee applies. Your friend should of asked the exit fees before agreeing to the service, if your friend has good reason to think that he has be mislead in a way then only then would it be a legal issue - but in all honesty for the sake of $15.00 pay it and move on and don't make the same mistake if you don't like their charges.

Comment: More like £7 as it was $15 (USD). Heh.

Comment: @GeoffJackson nicely spotted, I though it was in GBP... Ok, well $15 is completely normal then.